# how to display navigationMenu div left side of the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi in the below code how to display the navigation menu should be left side of the slider.
Now it's displaying bottom and center of the slider.But I want to navigation menu should be left side of the slider.

**html**

```
 <div id="slider">
      <ul id="images">
        <li><img src="img/1.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="gallery_buildings_one" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/2.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="gallery_buildings_two" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/3.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="gallery_buildings_three" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/4.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="gallery_buildings_four" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/5.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="gallery_buildings_five" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/6.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="gallery_buildings_six" /></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
     <div id="main">

<ul id="navigationMenu">
    <li>
        <a class="home" href="#">
            <span>Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="about" href="#">
            <span>About</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
         <a class="services" href="#">
            <span>Services</span>
         </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="portfolio" href="#">
            <span>Portfolio</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="contact" href="#">
            <span>Contact us</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

**css**

```
#navigationMenu li{
    list-style:none;
    height:39px;
    padding:2px;
    width:40px;
    position:left;
}

#navigationMenu span{
    /* Container properties */
    width:0;
    left:38px;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;

    /* Text properties */
    font-family:'Myriad Pro',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:0.6px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    line-height:39px;

    /* CSS3 Transition: */
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s;

    /* Future proofing (these do not work yet): */
    -moz-transition: 0.25s;
    transition: 0.25s;
}

#navigationMenu a{
    background:url('img/navigation.jpg') no-repeat;

    height:39px;
    width:38px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}



#navigationMenu a:hover span{ width:auto; padding:0 20px;overflow:visible; }
#navigationMenu a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;

    /* CSS outer glow with the box-shadow property */
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #9ddff5;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #9ddff5;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #9ddff5;
}

/* Green Button */

#navigationMenu .home { background-position:0 0;}
#navigationMenu .home:hover {   background-position:0 -39px;}
#navigationMenu .home span{
    background-color:#7da315;
    color:#3d4f0c;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #99bf31;
}

/* Blue Button */

#navigationMenu .about { background-position:-38px 0;}
#navigationMenu .about:hover { background-position:-38px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .about span{
    background-color:#1e8bb4;
    color:#223a44;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #44a8d0;
}

/* Orange Button */

#navigationMenu .services { background-position:-76px 0;}
#navigationMenu .services:hover { background-position:-76px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .services span{
    background-color:#c86c1f;
    color:#5a3517;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d28344;
}

/* Yellow Button */

#navigationMenu .portfolio { background-position:-114px 0;}
#navigationMenu .portfolio:hover{ background-position:-114px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .portfolio span{
    background-color:#d0a525;
    color:#604e18;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d8b54b;
}

/* Purple Button */

#navigationMenu .contact { background-position:-152px 0;}
#navigationMenu .contact:hover { background-position:-152px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .contact span{
    background-color:#af1e83;
    color:#460f35;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d244a6;
}
#main{
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    width:40px;
}
#slider { 
  width: 1500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;  
} 
ul#images {
  margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
ul#images li {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: left side means, float left or on top of left side ?

Comment: and can you create jsfiddler or jsbin for it

Comment: slider div left side

Comment: see friend I got the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    #main {
       margin: 0;
       position: relative;
       width: 40px;
       float: left;
       background: #ccc;
    }
<div id="main">

<ul id="navigationMenu">
    <li>
        <a class="home" href="#">
            <span>Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="about" href="#">
            <span>About</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
         <a class="services" href="#">
            <span>Services</span>
         </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="portfolio" href="#">
            <span>Portfolio</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="contact" href="#">
            <span>Contact us</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

</div>
<div id="slider">
      <ul id="images">
        <li><img src="img/1.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="gallery_buildings_one" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/2.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="gallery_buildings_two" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/3.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="gallery_buildings_three" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/4.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="gallery_buildings_four" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/5.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="gallery_buildings_five" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/6.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="gallery_buildings_six" /></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: on mouser button it show in backside of the slider I want to show to front side

Answer (score 0):

```
#navigationMenu li{
    list-style:none;
    height:39px;
    padding:2px;
    width:40px;
    position:left;
     }
```

remove position:left;
   from the css
  now update your css and add a new

```
#navigationMenu{
float:left;
position:absolute;
left:say 100px;
}
```

try that